# Why do I have to divide the total work in the method of images?

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

I got that potential, field and force don't need division since as long as it satisfies the boundary conditions it is correct as the answer is unique due to the uniqueness theorem.

But what qualities of work make only work different from the others?
I think I'm grasping it but it is still very vague that I can't explain to others satisfactorilly.

For example, there is a charge in the first quadrant. Then I would introduce image charges into the second, third and fourth.
Electric field, force, potential do not change because of the introduction but the work done by the real charge is fourths of the work done by the all charges together. Why is that?

Comment: Are you asking why when calculating work, one moves one charge and then another charge and so on, summing the result?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the image charges is to help you calculate the electric potential and electric field in the region of interest. Introducing an image charge in (say) a region occupied by a conductor doesn't introduce an electric field in that region.

When calculating the potential energy of the original situation, it may be useful to think in terms of energy-density and note that the energy-density in the conducting regions is zero since the field is zero there.

For example, for a charge above a conducting plane, the electric energy density is zero below the plane. So, the potential energy of the point charge above the conducting plane is half of what you get from the potential energy of a point charge above a real-version of the image charge.